# Creating 2 dimensional array in Python Flask application Jinja2 Template

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, flask, jinja2

Within my Flask index.html template I wish to create a 2 dimensional array within a for loop. The for loop works perfectly fine but trying to 'set' an array that's multidimensional is not working. For example, one of the many things I've tried is:

```
{% set matrix = [[] for x in range(sizeOfSomething)] %}
```

I get the following exception:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'for'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Jinja2 [won't allow list comprehensions](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/faq/#isn-t-it-a-terrible-idea-to-put-logic-into-templates) can you post a broader example of what you are trying to do? My guess is it is better to do this by passing variables to the template rather than do the logic inside it.

Comment: In the template I have a for loop which iterates through a list and within it I call another function from where I access more information. In the second for loop I need to set the 2d array to store the array and elements in order on which then i'd be tying a button to enable/disable services. I need all of this done dynamically, which is why i'm having an issue. I'm not sure if this is broad enough, if not I can try and elaborate more.

Comment: I'm generating a view that displays information from multiple servers dynamically within the template and I know of parameter passing but not sure how I would be able to display the information from the for app.py to the template dynamically as I am trying to right now. @SteveRossiter

Comment: Generally, it is much better to perform the control logic in the app.py and then pass the template a dictionary or a list of dictionaries to do this kind of thing. If you update your question with an example of your template someone may be able to show you how this can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jinja2 [won't allow list comprehensions](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/faq/#isn-t-it-a-terrible-idea-to-put-logic-into-templates) so this won't work.

The best approach is to take whatever you are doing in the loops and move it into app.py and pass the matrix to the template as a variable. You may find [custom filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#writing-filters) to be useful in processing the matrix within the template.

Comment: Thank you, I will be changing the code around more to do just that and then post my template if needed be by tomorrow morning sometime if I don't get it working by then.